# how to apply css on specific element by id

Tags: html, css

the template i'm using apply css on all nav and it overrides any css written for any other nav however i've written the css on this very specific nav using its id. i've read that the last css is applied and when i tried this the same result.

```
nav {
  width: 55%;
  float: left;
}
nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 2px;
  color:#dce3e4;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
  margin: 0 1px;
}
nav a {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

and here is the css i'm trying to apply:

```
#nav > a {
  display: none !important;
}

#nav li {
  position: relative !important;
}

#nav > ul {
  height: 3.75em !important;
}

#nav > ul > li {
  width: 25% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  float: left !important;
}

#nav li ul {
  display: none !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: You're right that CSS is applied top-down, but CSS also is applied to the selector that is the *most specific*. My guess is this is your problem, or the id `#nav` doesn't exist. In the end though, it's impossible to give a precise reason as to your problem without seeing the HTML structure of the code in question.

Answer (score 1):

In the original code there is `nav` (the HTML5 tag). In your added code there is `#nav` - an ID. Did you really use tags like `<nav id="nav">` in your code? If not, you have to change that.

Edit/addition:

After seeing your code in your comment, here are some more thoughts:

- the `#nav > a` rule won't be applied to that code: There is no `a` tag as a direct child of `#nav`
- `#nav li` has `position: relative` anyway - your rule doesn't change the one above.
- `#nav li ul`: There is no element in your code that this would apply to.

Maybe you have more code than you wrote in your comment to which these rules would apply. If yes, you should post your HTML code. But if that is already your complete HTML code in that `nav`, these are the reasons why these rules won't have any effect.

Comment: i use the very same tag that you mentioned
      `<nav id="nav">
         <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">JavaScript</a></li>
            </ul>
            </nav>`

Comment: this should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

You put in a comment that your HTML structure looks like this:

```
<nav id="nav"> 
    <ul> 
        <li><a href="/">Design</a></li> 
        <li><a href="/">HTML</a></li> 
        <li><a href="/">CSS</a></li> 
        <li><a href="/">JavaScript</a></li> 
    </ul> 
</nav>
```

And you're trying to select elements like, for example:

```
#nav > a {
    display: none !important;
}
```

The `>` character points to elements that are *immediate children* of the parent. You don't have an `<a>` element as an immediate child of `#nav`, for example. This is why your css isn't being picked up.

Comment: ok , but even for
    `#nav > ul`
and 
    `#nav > ul > li`
is not applied

Comment: @Desha It is being applied. Check out [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lx0st891/) and Inspect the list in your browser. You should also consider the dangers of using `!important` because you're probably going to be experiencing them if you're not already.

Comment: [link](http://osvaldas.info/drop-down-navigation-responsive-and-touch-friendly) i've tried the code written in this link using fiddle but also the same result appeared , i guess the code in this link is not the same as shown in the demo mentioned in the link

Comment: [Here's a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/44nm597L/2/) with everything from that site and your css.  It seems to be working for me - images not included of course.